# Equations Game. Finding solution for a random Goal from random Resource

Tags: javascript, arrays, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing an AI for a game called Equations in Javascript.

For the sake of the question, let's pretend that the game is this simple:

- There is a Goal, which can be a number(eg 5) or an expression (that can be
  evaluated to a number. eg: 2+3).
- There are 20 random numbers(1-9) and operators(+-*/) I can use, let's call them
  the array resources[]. I need to find one combination of the elements
  in resources[] that is evaluated to the Goal, let's call that the
  solution (eg 1+6-2+1).
- There is no limit of how many numbers or operators I can use, as long
  as they are in resource[]. Once they are used, they cannot be used
  again. So the longest solution might be 20 symbols long.

Is there a way I can quickly find such solution? The AI might need to evaluate this many times when analysing a move's score.

Thanks guys

Comment: Is this only for integral numbers?

Comment: Yeah, only natural numbers and 4 basic operators (+ - * /). I'm thinking of using dynamic programming: finding solutions for each number, up to the Goal.

Comment: The problem type seems well suited for Genetic Algorith, like explained [here](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat3.html). Unfortunately the resource constraint makes everything more complicated.